# Making macro depending on If

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to make C code, that will copy string into matrix of type double so i need to take strings from one of two inputs: stdin and .txt file. Is that possible to make line:

```
while(fgets(tmpbuffer, MAXLEN, stdin) != NULL)
```

and

```
while(fgets(tmpbuffer, MAXLEN, filepointer) != NULL)
```

working without copying whole functions? I mean... something like

```
#define stdin filepointer
```

but depending on parameter given by user (1 or 0 on stdin)?

Comment: This is a bad idea and a solution seeking a problem. `stdin` **is** a `FILE *`! And the idea in using functions is not to copy code. So if you define (language and larger context) your function properly, there is no need to "copy" your function.

Comment: You still need to copy the entire function for that. The *compiler* (more accurately, the *preprocessor*) would need to 'see' the function twice, each one with its own `define`. Just make it a function on its own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure! Consider just wrapping the whole thing in a function that takes a `FILE*` parameter:

```
void do_something(FILE* fp) {
    while (fgets(tmpbuffer, MAXLEN, fp) != NULL) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, you can call `do_something(stdin)` or `do_something(filepointer)` as appropriate.

Comment: this is due to the fact the stdin is 'just a file', it just happens to have been setup and opened for you by the c runtime

Comment: Thinking outside of the box. Genius! :-) +1

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a macro for this.

Instead of duplicating your code, what you really want to do is realize that `stdin` is nothing but just a `FILE *` pointer. So your code should look something like this.

```
FILE * fp = stdin;
if (filename != NULL) /* or whatever the condition */
  {
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot open file '%s' for reading: %s\n",
                filename, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
  }
/* Read from fp … */
if (fclose(fp) != 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot close file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

Note that this code will potentially `fclose(stdin)`. If your program doesn't want to read anything else from it, this shouldn't be a problem.